# Creating an anonymous post with disqus API fails

Tags: disqus

I am trying to use the Disqus API to post an anonymous commment, without success. I am using Fiddler Composer with the following settings:

```
POST http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json

Host: disqus.com
Referer: http://www.domain.com

thread=1271948405&message=test0xyanonnn&api_key=mypublickey&author_email=xxx@xxx.xd&author_name=xxx
```

The response I am getting is

```
{"code": 12, "response": "This application cannot create posts on the chosen forum
```

I have added the domain.com (my domain here) to the trusted domains in the API and website pages in Disqus admin.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Actually I posted an anonymous comment and using Fiddler I noticed a different API key was used (not to be found anywhere in my admin pages). The question now is, how can I pass the date parameter? Since I want to import old anonymous comments through the API, I need to also specify the actual date, but since the API request is anonymous, I cannot specify the 'date' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've founded solution. If you want to post as a guest you must replace that `api_secret` with `api_key` in the request which is "`E8Uh5l5fHZ6gD8U3KycjAIAk46f68Zw7C6eW8WSjZvCLXebZ7p0r1yrYDrLilk2F`"
and comments will be post.